# `overload_cast` fails in a specific case

Tags: c++, pybind11

I have found a specific case in which the `overload_cast` fails, and I have no idea how to solve this.

A minimal example that shows the behavior is

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

// ----------------

template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
void absolute(
  const InputIterator first, const InputIterator last, const OutputIterator result
)
{
  for ( auto it = first ; it != last ; ++it )
    *it = std::abs(*it);
}

// ----------------

std::vector<double> absolute(const std::vector<double> &in)
{
  std::vector<double> out = in;

  for ( auto &i: out )
    i = std::abs(i);

  return out;
}

// ----------------

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m)
{
  m.def("absolute", py::overload_cast<const std::vector<double>&>(&absolute));
}
```

Compiling using e.g.:

```
clang++ -O3 -shared -std=c++14 `python3-config --cflags --ldflags --libs` example.cpp -o example.so -fPIC
```

Gives:

```
example.cpp:32:21: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const
      detail::overload_cast_impl<const vector<double, allocator<double> > &>'
  m.def("absolute", py::overload_cast<const std::vector<double>&>(&absolute));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:727:20: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer
      template argument 'Return'
    constexpr auto operator()(Return (*pf)(Args...)) const noexcept
                   ^
/usr/local/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:731:20: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer
      template argument 'Return'
    constexpr auto operator()(Return (Class::*pmf)(Args...), std::false_type = {}) const noexcept
                   ^
/usr/local/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:735:20: note: candidate function template not viable:
      requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
    constexpr auto operator()(Return (Class::*pmf)(Args...) const, std::true_type) const noexcept
                   ^
1 error generated.
```

Removing the first function (that I do not which to overload), or changing its signature solves the problem. But that is obviously not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using sig = std::vector<double>(const std::vector<double> &in);

py::overload_cast<const std::vector<double>&>((sig*)&absolute)
```

Unlike almost anything else in C++, `&absolute` doesn't refer to an actual value or object.

Instead it refers to an overload set; in this case, an overload set that includes both a specific signature and a template.

Template pattern matching which is used to deduce `Return` fails.

By casting to a specific signature, `(sig*)&absolute` now refers to an object or value -- in this case, a pointer to a specific function.  Now template pattern matching can deduce the type of `Return`.

In C++, the general rule is that callables don't have specific signatures.  You can ask what a callable invoked with specific arguments returns, but it is bad form to ask a callable what arguments it wants to be invoked with.  It is also bad form to assume a callable is a PMF or a function pointer.

People hack around this all the time, and it leads to annoying errors like your code demonstrates.

Comment: Great, that indeed solves the problem! I think that I have some intuition as to what happens: you help the compiler to match the return? But maybe you can say something more intelligent than this?

Comment: @TomdeGeus Words added.

Comment: Great! That is very instructive! Unfortunately, I get only one upvote.

Comment: @TomdeGeus The arc of the SO voting universe is long, but it bends towards upvotes eventually.  (I got a +1 on this 4 years later, and saw your comment, and was amused by the long-tail-ness of upvotes)